# Refresh ArrayAdapter dynamically

Tags: android, autocomplete

I have an Activity with an AutoComplete box on it. Whenever the text changes, I want to call a web service and populate the ArrayAdapter with the new String[] returned. This part all works great, except the list in the UI isn't being refreshed when there are all new values in String[] schools. The original list populated in my onCreate always remains.

I read somewhere I needed to update it on the same thread the UI is running on, so I tried the Runnable listed in my code below. But that, as well as just updating my class variable schools does not work alongside notifyOnDataSetChange()

Where am I going wrong?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    schools = SchoolProxy.search("Co");
    autoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, schools);
    autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView)  findViewById(R.id.edit);
    autoComplete.addTextChangedListener(textChecker);
    autoComplete.setAdapter(autoCompleteAdapter);
}
    ...
    ....
    ...

final TextWatcher textChecker = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
    {
     schools = SchoolProxy.search(s.toString());
     runOnUiThread(updateAdapter);
    }
};

private Runnable updateAdapter = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
         autoCompleteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

};
```

As a less important side note, if each item in schools has a name \n city,state. Is it possible to have the city & state on a second line within the auto drop down box? Just for formatting purposes. Would look cleaner if I could.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried the `setNotifyOnChange(true)`? It is supposed to properly do what you are doing manually whenever you use methods that change the list `(add(T), insert(T, int), remove(T), clear())`. Perhaps you have to modify the array through these methods on the `ArrayAdapter`?

I'm not sure if the `ArrayAdapter` is actually holding the reference to schools or just copied the contents while constructing the `ArrayAdapter`. Maybe you can take a look at the AOSP code to see what they're doing in that constructor.

Comment: I will try adding true to the method tonight. If that does not work, I will try clearing the adapter, then looping through the string and adding elements individually (I hope this isn't the solution though).

But I will report back my findings and accept if you are correct.

Comment: I am going to go ahead and assume that I need to clear() then use either add() or insert(). I had the data setup as a String[]. But I am going to experiment with just returning it all as a JSONArray and doing a loop of it.

Similar to:

    schools = SchoolProxy.search(s.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) 
    {
         autoCompleteAdapter.add(schools[i]);
    }

Answer (score 1):

After you dynamically change adapter, just need to call:

```
AutoCompleteTextView.showDropdown()
```