# How to use Google API in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-api

I want to display suggestion as user types in text box same like Google.
 I am using  [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html) and I want to use [Google API](http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=YOURSEARCHEDTERM)/ my own web service for getting suggestion.
How `AutoCompleteTextView` can be used with API or any other web service ?

Thanks,
Ajinkya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this jar](http://code.google.com/p/gsearch-java-client/) to get the result in a List

```
 import gsearch.*;

 Client client = new Client();    
 List<Result> ajax = c.searchWeb("google ajax search");
```

Use this List in conjunction with the `ArrayAdapter`. Trigger this when new text is entered in the Edit box. Call `notifydatasetchanged()` every time new data is downloaded.

Comment: Thanks for the link. How can I use my web service instead of Googles ?

Comment: Your web service will return a JSON or XML, parse and populate the data set associated with the Adapter. See [this for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967814/refresh-arrayadapter-dynamically)

Comment: In the question I couldnt see the code which calls the web service.

Comment: Parsing of the web-service response is something that you have to implement. You are the designer of the web-service after all. There is plenty of help regarding parsing JSON and XML on [so]

Comment: I am bit familiar with parsing XML but I am talking about calling a web service. I dont have any idea about how to call a web service in android.

Comment: See [this snippet](http://www.androidsnippets.com/retrieve-json-from-a-rest-web-service) for JSON. [This for SOAP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-with-android) .. etc